Python Flask and Auth0
I'm trying to implement Auth0 into a project but can't figure out how exactly I put the authorization token in the header.
I've been following the Auth0 documentation but have gotten lost. Here is what I've tried so far:
auth.py

ENV_FILE = find_dotenv()
if ENV_FILE:
    load_dotenv(ENV_FILE)

oauth = OAuth(app)

oauth.register(
    "auth0",
    client_id=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret=env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    client_kwargs={
        "scope": "openid profile email",
    },
    server_metadata_url=f'https://{env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")}/.well-known/openid-configuration'
)

# decorator for requiring login
def login_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not session.get("user"):
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function

require_auth = ResourceProtector()
validator = Auth0JWTBearerTokenValidator(
    "dev-dzlqn0602x1umzhg.us.auth0.com",
    "https://localhost:5000"
)
require_auth.register_token_validator(validator)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return oauth.auth0.authorize_redirect(
        redirect_uri=url_for("callback", _external=True)
    )

@app.route("/callback", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def callback():
    token = oauth.auth0.authorize_access_token()
    session["user"] = token
    return redirect("/")

@app.route("/public")
def public():
    """No access token required."""
    response = (
        "Hello from a public endpoint! You don't need to be"
        " authenticated to see this."
    )
    return jsonify(message=response)

@app.route("/private")
@require_auth(None)
def private():
    """A valid access token is required."""
    response = (
        "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be"
        " authenticated to see this."
    )
    return jsonify(message=response)


@app.route("/private-scoped")
@require_auth("read:all")
def private_scoped():
    """A valid access token and scope are required."""
    response = (
        "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be"
        " authenticated and have a scope of read:all to see"
        " this."
    )
    return jsonify(message=response)

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(
        "https://" + env.get("AUTH0_DOMAIN")
        + "/v2/logout?"
        + urlencode(
            {
                "returnTo": url_for("home", _external=True),
                "client_id": env.get("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
            },
            quote_via=quote_plus,
        )
    )

